# Drupal increase pagination index to start from 1 instead of 0

Tags: drupal, pagination

Increase pagination index to start from 1 instead of 0.
So in URL instead of ?page=0 it should be ?page=1 for first page and then ?page=2 so on..

Comment: What have you tried already? You could do it in a module altering the views query, or maybe in the htaccess file.

Comment: Which pagination ? Contrib module ? From views ?

Comment: For view pagination.

Comment: I'm able to explode the url and increment the id number by 1. I'm doing this in hook_preprocess_node in .theme file. But I'm not able to change the url.

Answer (score 0):

This question is documented in [Drupal core issue #1818040](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1818040). It looks like the patch from [comment #15](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1818040#comment-9736627) needs to be re-rolled for the latest minor release. If you are working with a limited code line and have control over your content, that might be enough. However, in the long term it looks like a fix needs to be found for the fact that this implementation is going to break URLs on existing sites and potentially interfere with other contributed modules.

Side note: I would like to go ahead and call to your attention an article written by Edsger W. Dijkstra's titled ["Why numbering should start at zero"](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html). When you say "such and such event is happening in three days" you do not mean the day after tomorrow but rather the day after the day after tomorrow. Your count does not begin with today but rather tomorrow, as today is when you begin counting (today = 0).

TL;DR: In the case of your book, the first page you encounter is the beginning, and you cannot begin counting before you have begun reading.

Comment: Yeah I looked into it. I'm concerned that it needs to be fixed in future.